# id voltando errado ele puxa o +"id": +"user_id" igual sendo que era para ser diferente os ids no laravel, eu não mexi em nada apenas bugou e não sei

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, laravel

id voltando errado ele puxa o +"id": +"user_id": igual sendo que era para ser diferente os ids no laravel Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\admin\SaqueController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class SaqueController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //$totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->get();
        
        
        $totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->Join('users', 'saques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->orderBy('user_id','DESC')->get();     
        
        //$totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'saques.user_id')->get();
        dd($totalsaques);
        
        return view('admin.saque',compact('totalsaques'));
    }
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //$saquex = event::findOrFail($id);
        //$request->all();
        //$totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->where('id');
        $totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->where('id', '=', $id)->latest('valor')->first();
        //dd($totalsaques);



        return view('admin.saquedetalhe',compact('totalsaques'));
        //return view('admin.saquedetalhe',['saques'=>'saques']);
    }

}

Puxando no BLADE

    @foreach ($totalsaques as $totalsaques)
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ $totalsaques->id }}</th>
          <td>{{ $totalsaques->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $totalsaques->valor }}</td>
          <td>{{ $totalsaques->situacao }} <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/admin/saque{{ $totalsaques->id }}" role="button">Detalhes</a></td>
          
        </tr>
        @endforeach


dd

 

    +"id": 41
        +"user_id": 41
        +"tipo": "CPF"
        +"chave": ""
        +"valor": "2000,00"
        +"situacao": "Concluído"
        +"created_at": "2021-12-26 20:09:01"
        +"deleted_at": null
```

Answer (score 0):

O invés de utilizar o get() na consulta, utilize o toSql() para ver se a query tá sendo executada da maneira que vc quer.

```
$totalsaques = DB::table('saques')->Join('users', 'saques.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->orderBy('user_id','DESC')->toSql();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).